# Function not working in Python Multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, python-multiprocessing

This is my code which is working, but a little too slow.

```
def fsl(Df,p):
    NewDf = Df.copy()

    if p=='group1':
        try:
            del NewDf['sl']
            del NewDf['Y2030']
        except:
            pass

    selected_clusters = NewDf.loc[(NewDf['Group']==p) & (NewDf['Selected']=='Y'),'Clusters'].tolist()

    for i in selected_clusters:
        x = 0
        surplus = calc_surplus(x,i,p)
        while (surplus > 0) and (x < 100000):
            x += 100
            surplus = calc_surplus(x,i,p)
        NewDf.loc[(NewDf['Clusters']==i) & (NewDf['Group']==p),'sl']=x

    if p=='group1':
        NewDf['sl'] = NewDf['sl'].fillna(0)

    return NewDf
```

I would like the `surplus` for each `selected_cluster` to be calculated on parallel to speed up the process.

I moved those codes for parallel run to a new function, and tried to run it on `Multiprocessing.Pool` like this:

```
def parallel(i):
    x = 0
    surplus = calc_surplus(x,i,p)

    while (surplus > 0) and (x < 100000):
        x += 100
        surplus = calc_surplus(x,i,p)

    NewDf.loc[(NewDf['Clusters']==i) & (NewDf['Group']==p),'sl']=x
    if p=='group1':
        NewDf['sl'] = NewDf['sl'].fillna(0)

def fsl(Df,p):
    NewDf = Df.copy()

    if p=='group1':
        try:
            del NewDf['sl']
            del NewDf['Y2030']
        except:
            pass

    selected_clusters = NewDf.loc[(NewDf['Group']==p) & (NewDf['Selected']=='Y'),'Clusters'].tolist()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with Pool(4) as pool:
            pool.map(parallel,[i for i in selected_clusters])


    return NewDf
```

The problem is, the function `parallel` never runs when the function `fsl` is called. The column `sl` is never created. I think the mistake is in `pool.map` or `pool.starmap`, but i really can't seem to solve this.

I have seen other threads on Multiprocessing, but most of them don't quite apply to this. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Show us the definition of `calc_surplus()` and any functions it calls too.  Your code is slow, but I'm not convinced using multiple cores is the best way to speed it up.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! calc_surplus() is a long function that looks at another dataframe, creates several columns based on some arithmetic functions, and returns an integer.

I thought if i can run `calc_excess()` on parallel for each cluster in `selected_clusters`, that would speed it up.. why wouldn't it? any other suggestions to improve this function? Thanks once again!